# MongoDB text search on subdocuments with unknown structure

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents, each one with a nested document as the ones named "attributes" in this example:

```
document1: {
    description: 'text text etc',
    attributes: {
        Name: 'Alice',
        Height: '170',
        FavouriteColour: 'Blue'
    }
}

document2: {
    description: 'more text etc',
    attributes: {
        Name: 'Bob',
        State: 'NY'
    }
}
```

I don't know what are the names of the keys as they are user-defined.

I want to perform a text search on the values of all attributes in that document without having to specify the keys but in order to perform the text search I need exactly one text index for the [$text](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) query, so this is not possible:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {$text: {$search: 'NY'}}},
    {$group: {_id: {$meta: "textScore"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

Since I don't know what attributes I might have, is there a way to work around this and perform a text search on the attributes values and return documents that match the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but.

Yes: You can index all fields with string content like so:

```
> db.collection.ensureIndex({ "$**": "text" }, { name: "TextIndex" })
```

See [Create a Text Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/#index-all-fields).

But: if you can avoid it, don't have your data have unknown structure, especially if you are letting the keys and values be user defined. Could you do something like

```
{
    "description" : "text text etc",
    "attributes" : [
        { "key" : "Name", "value" : "Alice" },
        { "key" : "Height", "value" : "170" },
        { "key" : "FavouriteColour", "value" : "Blue" }
    ]
}
```

instead? See [How to Model Dynamic Attributes](http://askasya.com/post/dynamicattributes).

Comment: The first method you suggested works for my scenario. The alternative approach on how to model dynamic attributes you've suggested also works pretty well, sounds more sensible and maintainable. Thanks!